# Worksheetfunction.find no more values to find

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that looks to find individual words in cells. In order to find the words, it looks for the spaces between those words, using the worksheetfunction.find command.

This process works fine until it gets to the very last word in the cell. As there are no more spaces to find, it returns an error. I have tried to combat this error using the application.find command, but when I do that, it views everything as an error, and simply selects all the text in the cell.

What I am wondering is:

- Is there any way around the problem of not finding a space between the last space and the end of the cell, using the worksheetfunction.find command?
- What does the application.find command return an error (less important)?

> ```
> Dim a As Double
> Dim b As Double
> Dim c As Variant
> Dim d As Integer
> Dim e As String
> Dim f As Double
> Dim g As Variant
> Dim h As Variant
> Dim i As Integer
>
> a = 1
> f = 2
> i = 1
> b = Len(Cells(i, 1))
>
> While Cells(i, 1) <> vbNullString
>     While a < b
>
>         c = vbNullString
>         d = 0
>         e = vbNullString
>
>         c = WorksheetFunction.Find(Chr(32), Cells(i, 1), a)
>
>         If Not IsError(c) Then
>
>             d = c - a
>
>         ElseIf IsError(c) Then
>
>             d = b - a
>
>         End If
>
>         e = Mid(Cells(1, 1), a, d)
>
>         If Left(e, 4) = "true" Then
>             e = "'" & e
>
>         ElseIf Left(e, 5) = "false" Then
>             e = "'" & e
>
>         End If
>
>
>         If e <> vbNullString Then
>             Worksheets("Words").Cells(f, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Trim(e)
>             f = f + 1
>
>         End If
>
>         If Not IsError(c) Then
>             a = c + 1
>         Else
>             a = a + d
>         End If
>
>     Wend
>     i = i + 1
>     b = Len(Cells(i, 1))
>     a = 1
> Wend
> ```

Comment: `Find` returns a `Range`. If it doesn't find a result, it is `Nothing`. `IsError(c)` assumes a `Variant`, so it calls the default member which doesn't exist. You have to test to see if it's `Nothing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution: Wrapping the `Find` in an `On Error Resume Next`, then if your return result is an empty string, it will strike your `Else` criteria and you can get that last word in the cell:

**EDIT: After further testing, this seems to get a little screwed up when moving to the next row... But did this work before?**

```
Dim a As Double
Dim b As Double
Dim c As Variant
Dim d As Integer
Dim e As String
Dim f As Double
Dim g As Variant
Dim h As Variant
Dim i As Integer

a = 1
f = 2
i = 1
b = Len(Cells(i, 1))

While Cells(i, 1) <> vbNullString
    While a < b

        c = vbNullString
        d = 0
        e = vbNullString

        On Error Resume Next
        c = WorksheetFunction.Find(Chr(32), Cells(i, 1), a)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If c <> "" Then

            d = c - a

        Else

            d = b - a + 1

        End If

        e = Mid(Cells(1, 1), a, d)

        If Left(e, 4) = "true" Then
            e = "'" & e

        ElseIf Left(e, 5) = "false" Then
            e = "'" & e

        End If


        If e <> vbNullString Then
            Worksheets("Words").Cells(f, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Trim(e)
            f = f + 1
        End If

        If c <> "" Then
            a = c + 1
        Else
            a = a + d
        End If

    Wend
    i = i + 1
    b = Len(Cells(i, 1))
    a = 1
Wend
```

[image: img1]

Here's how I would do it, if I were writing from scratch. By using `Split`, we can separate a cell's value by a specific delimiter (in our case, a space character), then write all those characters to their destination:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim temparr As Variant

Set sht = ActiveSheet
k = 1

For i = 1 To sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    temparr = Split(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")
    For j = 0 To UBound(temparr)
        Sheets("Words").Cells(k, 1).Value = temparr(j)
        k = k + 1
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

[image: img2]

Comment: TBH, I don't know why you wouldn't just `Split` the contents of the cell to get the tokens.  The OP's code is ***way*** too complicated.

Comment: @Comintern Yes good point - splitting into an array with the delimiter of a space character would probably be much better.

Comment: @Comintern never heard of Split or tokens. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Clauric I'll post you an example in a second.